# How to export query results to csv in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to export custom query to csv file I wrote the following command:

```
sqlcmd [-S myserver -d mydb -E -Q "SELECT column1 ,column_date, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, column_date) AS day_of_week ,distinc_events_count ,total_events_count ,event_duration FROM dbo.event_daily_stats ORDER BY column1" -o "D:\MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700]
```

but it returned the following error message:

```
The identifier that starts with '-S myserver -d mydb -E -Q "SELECT column1 ,column_date, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, column_date) AS day_of_week ,distinc_events_count ,' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
```

Does anyone know how this issue could be solved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I executed the command without "[" and "]" with no problem, have you tried in this way?

```
sqlcmd -S myserver -d mydb -E -Q "SELECT column1 ,column_date, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, column_date) AS day_of_week ,distinc_events_count ,total_events_count ,event_duration FROM dbo.event_daily_stats ORDER BY column1" -o "D:\MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700
```

Comment: I pasted the command changing only the query, myserver and mydb values and i did not receive any error. Maybe you accidentally deleted the "-" before "S". Can you paste the command you used?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're trying to run this inside of SSMS when it should be run at a command prompt instead.